# Remove selected nodes from a JSON stream

Tags: java, json, streaming

I need to serve JSON from from my backend to the user. But before sending it over the wire I need to remove some data because it's confidential, every element who's key starts with `conf_`.

Assume I have the following JSON source:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "conf_author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "conf_price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "conf_author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "conf_price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "conf_author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "conf_price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "conf_author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "conf_price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "conf_price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

Since the structure of the soruce JSON may vary (is not known), I need a way to identify the elements to remove by a pattern based on the key name `(^conf_)`.
So the resulting JSON should be:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "Sword of Honour"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8"
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red"
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

Since my source JSON will have 1m+ entries in the books array where every entry will have 100+ fields (child objects), I'm looking for some stream / event based approach like StAX rather then parsing the whole JSON into a JSONObject for manipulation for performance and resource reasons.

I looked at things like `Jolt`, `JSONPath` and `JsonSurfer` but these libraries did me get anywhere so far.

Can anyone provide some details on how my use case could be implemented best?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's Streaming API which can be used to parse huge JSON upto even giga bytes of size.It can be used to process huge files without loading them completely in memory.It allows get the data you want and ignore what you don't want also

Read more: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi